# iterate the json array and push each value to the list in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, angularjs

I am very new to angular JS.My question is, I have a json array that I am getting as ajax response from php page. I am iterating that json array and I want to push each value in the list like

```
angular.forEach($scope.companies.area, function(value, key) {
      $scope.comp = [
         { 'name': value1 },
         { 'name': value2 },
         { 'name': value3 }
      //...
      ]
});
```

How can I make this list?
My Json data is

{"1":"Audugodi","2":"Airforce Station Yelahanka","3":"Agaram","4":"Anadanagar","5":"Arabic College","6"
:"Banasawadi","7":"Banashankari","8":"Banashankari II Stage","9":"Banashankari III Stage","10":"Bangalore
 city","11":"Bangalore GPO","12":"Bannerghatta","13":"Bannerghatta Road","14":"Basavanagudi","15":"Basaveswaranagar"
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be easier using a simple `Array.prototype.map`:

```
  $scope.comp = $scope.companies.area.map(function(value) {
      return { name: value };
  });
```

As your data is actually in an object format, will have to change a bit to use it with .map (the original JSON data is at the bottom for reference):

```
helloApp.controller("CompanyCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('class_locaality.php?flag=1').success(function (data) {
        $scope.companies = data; // the original data - we need data.area
        $scope.comp = Object.keys(data.area).map(function (key) { // turn the object into a array of keys that we can iterate
                return {
                    name : data.area[key] // get the value from the original data.area using the key
                };
            });
    }).error(function (data) { // log error }); });


{
    "1" : "Audugodi",
    "2" : "Airforce Station Yelahanka",
    "3" : "Agaram",
    "4" : "Anadanagar",
    "5" : "Arabic College",
    "6" : "Banasawadi",
    "7" : "Banashankari",
    "8" : "Banashankari II Stage",
    "9" : "Banashankari III Stage",
    "10" : "Bangalore city",
    "80" : "St.Thomas Town",
    "81" : "Subramanyanagar",
    "95" : "Yelahanka",
    "96" : "Yeshwanthpur"
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is much cleaner than `forEach` + `push`!

Comment: Its not working here. My code is

var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", []);
helloApp.controller("CompanyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.post('class_locaality.php?flag=1').
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.companies = data;
      $scope.comp = $scope.companies.area.map(function(value) {
            return { name: value };
      });
    }).
    error(function(data) {
      // log error
    });
});

Comment: Can you post the JSON you get in the AJAX response ? (edit your original questions, and add it)

Comment: {
    "1": "Audugodi",
    "2": "Airforce Station Yelahanka",
    "3": "Agaram",
    "4": "Anadanagar",
    "5": "Arabic College",
    "6": "Banasawadi",
    "7": "Banashankari",
    "8": "Banashankari II Stage",
    "9": "Banashankari III Stage",
    "10": "Bangalore
 city",
    "80": "St.Thomas
 Town",
    "81": "Subramanyanagar",
   "95": "Yelahanka",
    "96": "Yeshwanthpur"
}

Comment: When you say it isnt working than what error you see in console?

Comment: @rohitjaiswal - fixed it to fit your data format - see edited answer.

Comment: @immirza .. I am getting this error

Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/modulerr?p0=helloApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.17%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DhelloApp%0Au%2F%3C%40h blah blah

Comment: @OriDrori   Thank you. Its working beautifully. :D :D

Comment: @OriDrori.  I got one more similar problem.

 $scope.comp = Object.keys(data.area).map(function (key) { 
                return {
                    name : data.area[key] 
                };
            });
Now i have also data.brand and data.malls and now I want return like 

            return{
                   name  :data.area[key],
                   brands:data.brands[key],
                   malls   :data.malls[key]
           }

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very specific to Angular. You can do exactly as you say: *push* the values into the array:

```
$scope.comp = [];
$scope.companies.area.forEach(function(value) {
    $scope.comp.push({ name: value });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An example copied from [here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/transforming-arrays-with-array-map.html) without using .Map

```
var colors = [
    {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }, // White
    {r: 128, g: 128, b: 128 }, // Gray
    {r: 0,   g: 0,   b: 0   }  // Black
];

var newColors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    transformed = {
        r: Math.round( colors[i].r / 2 ),
        g: Math.round( colors[i].g / 2 ),
        b: Math.round( colors[i].b / 2 )
    };

    newColors.push(transformed);
}

// Outputs:
// [
//    {r: 128, g: 128, b: 128 },
//    {r: 64,  g: 64,  b: 64  },
//    {r: 0,   g: 0,   b: 0   }
// ];
console.log(newColors);
```

Using .map

```
var newColors = colors.map(function(val) {
    return {
        r: Math.round( val.r / 2 ),
        g: Math.round( val.g / 2 ),
        b: Math.round( val.b / 2 )
    };
});
```

For explanation read this excellent [article](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/transforming-arrays-with-array-map.html)